# cannot use sdwebimage category (mach linker errors)

Tags: ios, linker-errors, sdwebimage

I want to use `SDWebImage` for my imageviews so that i can get images from the web. I downloaded the zip from github, unzipped it. I dragged files from SDWebImage folder into xcode, checked copy items, and also checked my target. Then, I did an import with `#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"`. I made two `UIImageViews` and I am using the method

`[self.sdFeedImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:feed.pictureURL]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];`

But when i tried to run my project, the build failed with 8 Apple Mach-O Linker errors. What is a Apple Mach-O Linker error? Upon choosing an error in the left pane of xcode, I see the this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex", referenced from:
      ___59-[SDWebImageDownloaderOperation connection:didReceiveData:]_block_invoke_0 in SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.o
  "_CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex", referenced from:
      ___59-[SDWebImageDownloaderOperation connection:didReceiveData:]_block_invoke_0 in SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.o
  "_CGImageSourceCreateIncremental", referenced from:
      ___59-[SDWebImageDownloaderOperation connection:didReceiveData:]_block_invoke_0 in SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.o
  "_CGImageSourceUpdateData", referenced from:
      ___59-[SDWebImageDownloaderOperation connection:didReceiveData:]_block_invoke_0 in SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKAnnotationView", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MKAnnotationView_$_WebCache in MKAnnotationView+WebCache.o
  "_kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight", referenced from:
      ___59-[SDWebImageDownloaderOperation connection:didReceiveData:]_block_invoke_0 in SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.o
  "_kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth", referenced from:
      ___59-[SDWebImageDownloaderOperation connection:didReceiveData:]_block_invoke_0 in SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Edit:**
Here is code:

```
self.sdUserImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 26, 51, 51)]; [self.contentView addSubview:self.sdUserImageView];
self.sdFeedImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 110, 284, 174)]; [self.contentView addSubview:self.sdFeedImageView];
```

then

```
[self.sdUserImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"graph.facebook.com/%@/… imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: Have you included 'ImageIO' and 'MapKit' frameworks?

Comment: I just included those, I also included CoreImage. The errors are gone, and I can now run the app. But no images are being downloaded and shown, I just see blank white space where I was expecting an image.

Comment: Wonder I could see your code then only I will be able to help ya. :)

Comment: in my custom cell...i have this code in initwithstyle method self.sdUserImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 26, 51, 51)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.sdUserImageView];
        
        self.sdFeedImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 110, 284, 174)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.sdFeedImageView] then [self.sdUserImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",feed.posterId]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];